# Kendo UI Grid - Grouping Table Header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to implement the functionality of Collapse/Expand all (in AngularJs) for grouped Kendo UI Grid and add it to the Grid's header. Do you have any idea how could I put my functionality in there (see the attached file). Thanks!

[Dojo with a normal grid with grouping activated](http://dojo.telerik.com/ejeQI)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically create a `button` element on `k-group-cell k-header` element:

```
var expandCollapseAll = document.createElement('button');
expandCollapseAll.innerHTML = ">";
var elementToAppend = document.getElementsByClassName("k-group-cell k-header");
elementToAppend[0].appendChild(expandCollapseAll);
expandCollapseAll.onclick = toggleExpandCollapse;
```

The `toggleExpandCollapse` function would trigger the `click` event of all `.k-icon.k-collapse` and `.k-icon.k-expand` elements on the grid.

To collapse all:

```
$("#grid").find(".k-icon.k-collapse").trigger("click");
```

To expand all:

```
$("#grid").find(".k-icon.k-expand").trigger("click");
```

I have created a [sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T64Kb/112/) to demonstrate the above in action.

NOTE: The CSS of the button is a little off but this should be enough to get you going :)